# Tradingview backtest shows different price than the script close price

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

In my script (pine v5) I have a simple close order on the bar close:

```
if close <= stop_loss
   if barstate.isconfirmed
      strategy.close(id = "Long", comment=exitLongComment)
```

On the live exchange this executes at price 0.4438.
When I print str.tostring(close), is also prints 0.4438.

However, on the Price column in the backtest it shows 0.4479! This number is used for PnL calculation.

**What is causing this discrepancy?**

[image]

These are my settings (I tried unchecking the last box too, no difference).

[image]

I noticed that the close time is given 1 bar ahead, e.g. this trade executed at 13:00 but shows at 12:00, I think this has to do with enabling one calculation before bar closes. Would be grateful if the backtest results could be exact as this is worrying.

-- Update --

I pinpointed that the 'calculate after order if filled' causes this discrepancy. This seems like it should not be the case. What is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

[barstate.isconfirmed](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_barstate%7Bdot%7Disconfirmed) and [Broker emulator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Strategies.html#broker-emulator) could contradict each other

On the other hand, for *Stop Loss* do not use `strategy.close`. Use `strategy.exit`
Something like this:

```
if strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit(
      id             = 'Long Exit',
      from_entry     = 'Long',
      stop           = stop_loss,
      comment_loss   = exitLongComment)
```

Comment: In this case I did not want continuous checking of the stop loss like exit() but only one check at the end of the bar. Mostly because I don’t want signals to be sent 1s away from eachother as my broker can’t deal with waiting until and order is open before closing it.  It’s strange that the barstate cause such an indistrepancy.